# sql teradata regex contains pattern matching

Tags: sql, regex, teradata, contains

I have a column like below in teradata. I want to extract all rows where just 'FEMA' is present. I dont want to find words that contain fema at start, or in middle or at the end. Generally in python I would do such search using `\bfema\b`. How could I achieve same results in teradata. I am thinking of something like `where Col1 contains ('\bfema\b')`

Col1
females are important
and the rule is called FEMA

Comment: So use regexp functions: http://dwgeek.com/teradata-regular-expressions-examples.html/

Comment: `select * from table1 where regexp_like(Col1, '(?i)\bfema\b')`?

Comment: what is the purpose of `(?i)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regexp_instr here:

```
select
*
from
<your table>
where
regexp_instr(<your column>,'\bFEMA\b') > 0
```

If you aren't concerned about case sensitivity, you can use
`regexp_instr(upper(<your column>),'\bFEMA\b') > 0`